# How can I fix this issue, installing the Google Cloud SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can't seem to find a way to install the Google cloud platform. I have tried to download from the Eclipse Marketplace, from the web page; and nothing.

After some work, I have reached the point where in the installation terminal, they ask me if I want to UPDATE %PATH% to include CLOUD SK Binaries?

**I put yes and this happens:**

[image: GoogleCloud]

**even though my system variables are:**

[image: SystemVariables]

Please Help

Comment: Instructions to install the sdk can be found in the below link check this out https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it installing it in a new windows vm from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows) and the `%PATH%` the installation created is not the same as yours. In my case it was

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin
```

Are you sure Cloud SDK binaries are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google-cloud-sdk\bin`?